# Multiple conditions in a SELECT statement?

Tags: abap, opensql

First off, I have no experience with ABAP, I'm operating on guesswork here.

I want to add a condition to a SELECT in an existing report.
The existing code looks like this:

```
SELECT SINGLE *
  FROM EKPO
  WHERE EBELN = GT_MSEG-EBELN
  AND   EBELP = GT_MSEG-EBELP.
```

I want to add a condition to exclude the record if field F1 is a certain value and field F2 is 0 (both conditions must be true to exclude the record). I've tried this:

```
SELECT SINGLE *
  FROM EKPO
  WHERE EBELN = GT_MSEG-EBELN
  AND   EBELP = GT_MSEG-EBELP
  AND NOT (F1 = 'value' AND F2 = '0').
```

I get a syntax error: Field "F1 = 'value' AND F2 = '0'" is unknown. It is neither in one of the specified tables nor defined by a "DATA" statement.

Fields F1 and F2 definitely exist in the EKPO table, I've checked. It seems that the brackets are making the compiler look at the contents as a field name, but I don't know why.

Is the syntax incorrect, am I missing a definition somewhere, or both?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT SINGLE *
  FROM EKPO
  WHERE EBELN = GT_MSEG-EBELN
  AND   EBELP = GT_MSEG-EBELP
  AND NOT ( F1 = 'value' AND F2 = '0' ).
```

This worked. Basically I just needed a space adjacent to the brackets.

Comment: for the future: almost everything in ABAP needs that space, like method calls.