# And + Or in one Select-Statement

Tags: select, abap, opensql

In my select statement I chain different conditions with AND. Now I need for one condition an OR.
How can I add this for just this one Attribute without affecting the other AND-statements before?
That's my coding:

`SELECT pernr reinr pdatv pdatb pdvrs abrec FROM PTRV_PERIO
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
    WHERE pdatv GE pa_begda
    AND   pdatb LE pa_endda
    AND   abrec EQ '2'.`

For the last condition `abrec EQ '2'` I need an OR as well, like `abrec EQ '2' OR '3'`.
How can I add this the best way without affecting the other ANDs?

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: parentheses ?   `A and B and C and (D Or E)`

Comment: SELECT pernr reinr pdatv pdatb pdvrs abrec FROM PTRV_PERIO
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
    WHERE pdatv >=pa_begda
    AND   pdatb <=pa_endda
    AND   (abrec ='2' OR abrec ='3')

Comment: Hey guys, thanks you for the quick response. I missed to say that I'm working in ABAP, sorry for that. Right now it doesn't looks like it works in ABAP like that. I still get errors with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parentheses:

**EDIT:** Seems like you need to add spaces after and before the brackets
See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623637/how-do-i-group-conditions-in-a-select-statement-in-abap).

```
SELECT pernr reinr pdatv pdatb pdvrs abrec FROM PTRV_PERIO
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
WHERE pdatv GE pa_begda
AND   pdatb LE pa_endda
AND   ( abrec EQ '2' OR abrec EQ '3' )
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks you for the quick response. I missed to say that I'm working in ABAP, sorry for that. Right now it doesn't looks like it works in ABAP like that. I still get errors with it.

Comment: @Suncatcher I found a related question. Check the updated answer.

Comment: It is **invalid** syntax! It is insufficient to find alike question and fill answer from there. Just RTFM.

Comment: Sorry, I have mistaken you with Dyrdek and I didn't see that you've already provided the correct answer.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. It was really just the missing spaces. It works fine with your updated answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [IN clause](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_740/en/abenwhere_logexp_list.htm) instead:

```
SELECT pernr reinr pdatv pdatb pdvrs abrec FROM PTRV_PERIO
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
WHERE pdatv GE pa_begda
AND   pdatb LE pa_endda
AND   abrec IN ('2', '3').
```

The other valid alternative is:

```
SELECT pernr reinr pdatv pdatb pdvrs abrec FROM PTRV_PERIO
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_ptrv_perio
WHERE pdatv GE pa_begda
AND   pdatb LE pa_endda
AND   ( abrec EQ '2' OR abrec EQ '3' ).
```